# Android application in nodejs

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying to make an application for android using node.js. As far as I searched, I found [anode](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode). But is there any proper tutorial or example to get started? I have no idea how.

Comment: Is [https://github.com/paddybyers/anode/wiki/Anode](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode/wiki/Anode) enough?

Comment: I saw that but it not very clear. Im looking for a hello world example or a complete tutorial

Answer (score 1):

As a junior Android Developer I think this is not a good idea because mainly the major issue in android development are the layouts and some API (at least for me)... If you want to go with async and node-like dev on android try rxjava

Answer (score 0):

I would go through a java tutorial first before you try to look into node.  The fact of the matter is you are not going to find as many resources for node as you will for java. Once you are super familiar with the android stack it should be easy to write it in node with little documentation.

Comment: I know java for 1 year, though not android

Comment: try this tutorial it will get you from 0 to 60 if you already know java. https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853